# Extend displaying values of bar plot to multivariate stacked bar

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I have been told that it is better to split up sub questions into multiple topics on SE, so here I go.

I have adapted [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866705/centering-values-in-r-with-ggplot2) to be presentable in [a multivariate stacked bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803031/plotting-a-bivariate-to-multiple-factors-in-r). Everything works fine, however the values are not displaying correctly.

```
dnom <- data.frame(Variant = sample(c("iedere","elke"),size = 50,replace = TRUE),
        Region = sample(c("VL","NL"),size = 50,replace = TRUE),
        PrecededByPrep = sample(c("1","0"),size = 50,replace = TRUE),
        Person = sample(c("person","no person"),size = 50,replace = TRUE),
        Time = sample(c("time","no time"),size = 50,replace = TRUE))

ggplot.labs <- data.frame(table(dnom))
# OR?
ggplot.data <- melt(dnom, id.vars = "Variant")
ggplot.data <- ddply(ggplot.labs, .(Var1), transform, pos = cumsum(Freq) - (0.5 * Freq))

ggplot(dnom, aes(x=Variant)) +
        geom_bar(aes(fill=Variant)) + 
        geom_text(data=ggplot.labs, aes(x=Var1, label=Freq, y=Freq/2), size=3) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("paleturquoise3", "palegreen3")) +
        theme_corpling() +
        labs(x="Variant", y="Frequentie", title="Distributie van varianten") +
        guides(fill=FALSE)
```

But as you can see I am not sure how to merge `ddply` and `melt` (as provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803031/plotting-a-bivariate-to-multiple-factors-in-r#answer-27838986)). How should I go about this?

Comment: You tabulate over Region, which has two levels, so why do you expect more than two values? Did you mean `table(dnom$Region, dnom$Variant)`? [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2/6645506#6645506) may be a relevant post.

Comment: @Henrik Oops my bad. Fixed it! I simply don't know how to position these values relative to the bars. I have seen that post (and basically every other post on the whole internet that concerns itself with bar plots) and I still can't figure this out...

Comment: @Henrik Please see my edit, I tried (again) to apply that solution, however it doesn't work out.

Comment: Please study the linked answer carefully. They use `cumsum` on the already _aggregated_ data. Thus, in `ddply` you need to replace "dnom" with "dnom_labs". You also need to change relevant variable names in `ddply` and `ggplot`. Finally, because you use aggregated data, you need `stat = "identity"`.

Comment: @Henrik I was close! Couldn't figure out what "Freq" referred to, but with the help of the answer below I figured it out. Unfortunately I still haven't figured out how to apply this to my advanced plot mentioned in my OP. I don't know how to use `ddply` and `melt` along side each other.

Comment: @Henrik Please see my edit. This is now not a duplicate, as it is directed on multivariate bar plotting.

Comment: Just a small note: no problem with the edits _per se_, but in general you should be careful so that your question doesn't become a moving target. People have spent their time trying to solve the original question.

Comment: @Henrik I'm aware of that, though I didn't think it was worth it to post yet another question concerning this. Could you please remove the duplicate label? I don't think there's any exact duplicate on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something was lost in translation between the answer you linked to and your adaptation of it.

```
# Code from an older edit of the question.
dnom_labs <- data.frame(table(dnom$Region, dnom$Variant))

# Suggested answer
Data <- ddply(dnom_labs, .(Var1), transform, pos = cumsum(Freq) - (0.5 * Freq))

ggplot(Data, aes(x=Var1, y = Freq)) +
        geom_bar(aes(fill=Var2), stat = "identity") + 
        geom_text(aes(label = Freq, y = pos), size = 3) +
        labs(x="Region", y="Frequencies", title="Distribution of variant")
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine for the "simple" stacked plots (+1), but do you have any idea how to apply this to [a bivariate multiple plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803031/plotting-a-bivariate-to-multiple-factors-in-r)?

Comment: It seems you managed to get an answer to that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27838986/937932).